# How to hide all the marketing and sales stuff in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to set up dynamics for a call centre that just wants to do cas management. How do I turn off these things off so there is no evidence of them for a user of the system?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good place to start would be to edit the SiteMap.

There is a [project on codeplex which might be helpful](http://sitemapeditor.codeplex.com/), otherwise you can find good guides dotted around the place:

- [Editing the SiteMap](http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crmmitchmilam/archive/2010/11/29/crm-2011-editing-the-sitemap.aspx)
- [Editing the SiteMap 2](http://nicolaet.wordpress.com/2010/11/19/customizing-the-site-map-in-dynamics-crm-2011/)

With this you could hide Sales & Marketing, which would be a good start. You may also want to look at amending permissions for Leads/Opportunities which can be done by [editing security roles](http://www.dynamicscrmtrickbag.com/2011/07/20/dynamics-crm-2011-security-roles/). This will help nosey/inquisitive users from creating records if they find links elsewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I presume that you are referring to the subsections of the native CRM navigation structure which shows Workplace, Sales, Marketing, Service and Settings.

Visibility of these areas can be driven in two different ways. You may choose to employ both methods.

Firstly record-type visibility is governed by a user's permissions. Remove a users read access to Invoices for example and it will cease to appear as a navigable option in their UI. Similarly the sub-areas that I previously mentioned will cease to appear if a user has no access to any of the record types that it contains.
 consequently it may be possible to achieve some of your aims by giving users the least possible permissions required to do their job (though you should be doing this anyway really) by granting the correct ouot-of-the-box roles or cloning and customising one of those roles. The problem is that the Sales section , for example, contains record types that your users will need to see, e.g. contacts. you won't be able to revoke access to contacts so you'll likely need technique #2 as well:

The CRM sitemap can be customized to contain whatever you want and can even contain new areas. One feature available is to alter or create rules that show/hide areas based on record permissions. I'd recommend downloading the [Visual SiteMap Editor](http://dynamics.pinpoint.microsoft.com/en-us/applications/microsoft-dynamics-crm-sitemap-editor-12884928049) and read this part of the [CRM SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309259.aspx)

Comment: wish I could mark both of these answers as correct...thanks for directing me to the SDK and The SiteMap Editor both were helpful

Comment: No worries Peter. @glosrob must have started his answer at exactly the same time. Might have beaten him if i wasnt on my smartphone at the time ;) heh!